# Notepad++: is it possible to open from command line without gutter?

Tags: command-line, notepad++

I'd like to open notepad++ from command line (in fact, via AutoHotKey) with several params changes, like without gutter (at the same time, the "main" n++ window is opened with gutter). I've only found [these docs](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches) regarding available params (and already use `-notabbar`), but I'm not sure if it is up-to-date. Is there a way to pass a "nogutter" param when launching n++ from cmd? Or should I make a feature request?

In fact, I'm looking for more params (different from what I use in the "main" n++ window), namely: no gutter, increased font size, show only file name in window title (not the full path), so hints about any of these options are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "gutter"?

Comment: @DavidPostill hm, sorry, I thought it's a generally recognized term. It's a vertical band on the left side of an editor, where line numbers, fold code block buttons etc are shown. Left margin, one could call it (like on this picture: http://img.izhangheng.com/2013/11/sublime-text-crack-mac-osx.jpg)

Comment: You can turn the line number off in Preferences -> Editing.

Comment: I wonder if you can do something like have a different config file (with changed settings) and have a batch file that copies the config over the normal one, runs notepad++, and then restores the normal config when you close notepad++

Comment: You can set Folder Margin Style to none, also in Preferences -> Editing.

Comment: Settings are stored in `%appdata%\Notepad++\config.xml`

Comment: Preferences -> MISC Show only filename in title bar

Comment: @DavidPostill yeap, I know how to change those options globally, the issue is if this is possible to set those for a separate window via command line. I've thought about the config file, too, but restoring *when n++ is closed* is not something I know how to do either.. but hey, may be this can be done by changing config.xml, launching n++ and restoring config.xml *directly after* we launched that instance of n++. I'll try this one, I think

Comment: That *may* work, but if you change any prefs while notepad++ is open it will overwrite config.xml.

Comment: "restoring when n++ is closed is not something I know how to do either" a batch file can do that. You would need to leave it running though.

Comment: Do you think you can have multiple instances of Notepad++ with different settings and always launch the one with expected settings?

Comment: @miroxlav well, for some settings that's true and tested (I refer to those allowed from command line): currently I use `-notabbar -nosession -lpython` for "non-main" windows and they don't interfere with the main window's session/settings). The point is, non-main windows are launched by an AHK script so yes, they have different settings.

Comment: Good. So problem solved?

Comment: Nope, the question is about the gutter. I haven't tried what we discussed with David yet, though.